# mv command failing because destination already exists

Tags: linux, copy, rsync, mv

Sorry if this has been answered - I tried to search, but didn't find anyone with quite the same issue..

I'm trying to basically move all files from one drive (mountpoint) to another..  I initially used

mv /mnt/old1/* /mnt/disk1

This SEEMS to have been working, but I had a power failure in the middle of it, and when I re-issue the command, it seems to be having issues because the directory structure in the destination already exists, so it's not moving the source files anymore.

Basically, at this point, I'm just trying to merge two directory structures into one.  I guess I could cp the structure, but I would really have no way to know if a file was skipped as I do with mv, since if it's still in the source drive, I can assume it wasn't moved..

Is there a better way to do this?  I've never used rsync, but from what I'm reading, perhaps this is a better option?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I've got millions of files (18+tb) to move and I don't want to inadvertently miss something..

Thanks!
Steve

Comment: `rsync` *is* a better option.

Comment: Use with care. rsync can silently erase the dest folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following, and it works.

```
mv -ui /old/* /new/
-u for update mode
-i for query if exist (just for double check, maybe useless)
```

I do not know whether slash "/" after "/new" matters, and after that, files in /old/ are those not moved.

Hope this can help :)